# ASP:DropDownList vertical text alignment in Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox, alignment

I have a selection of textboxes and dropdown lists on an ASP.net page, using the ASP:DropDownList control.

They all display fine in chrome, IE, opera, safari, but in FF I get:

[image]

Note "Please Select" is aligned Top in the dropdownlist.

code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" onclick="changeBorderColor(this.id)" forecolor="White"  style="border:none; Width:352px; font-size:15px; font-family:Arial, helvetica, Verdana; height:35px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 1px solid rgb(124, 201, 25); border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px; box-shadow:0px 0px 9px rgb(191, 191, 191) inset; padding-left:10px; " ID="Country" Width="282px" >
```

I have tried assing some "padding-top:" but it causes other issues.

How can i get the text to display in the vertical center of the control?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `vertical-align` use `line-height` 30 or something. try something between 20 and 30

Comment: Sorry the vertical-align was a left-over from trying to fix it (now removed) - tried line-height but that had zero effect

Comment: heigth: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
line-height: 20px;

Comment: i cant give u an actual answer when im not seing the page infront of me so im just givin you something down the lines

Answer (score 1):

The best solution i ever came with is to give `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. Let's say now you have `font-size: 15px;` and `height: 35px;`, so this means `20px` spare, so add `padding-top: 10px` and `padding-bottom: 10px` and text should be centered vertically in the middle of your `input`.

Comment: Thanks - that Semi-works - it fixes the vertical alignment, however it does shrink the dropdown arrow box (by the amount of padding applied top and bottom)

Comment: Have you removed `height: 35px`? This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uejJj/) I created. First dropdown is without `height`